Understanding Python Error message: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (183,) (182,)
I'm new to python and unfortunately I'm not sure how to share a reproductible example. I'm looking for anomalies in a dataset for an anti-fraud exercice. I'm trying to use the Z-score to find outliers. However, I get an error code. I think the issue is the shape of the data (not sure) but I have no idea how to fix that. Any pointer would help! thanks!
from scipy.stats import zscore
daily_fraud['zscore'] = zscore(daily_fraud.values)
anomalies = daily_fraud[daily_fraud['zscore'].abs() >2]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in zscore(a, axis, ddof)
   2313                 np.expand_dims(sstd, axis=axis))
   2314     else:
-> 2315         return (a - mns) / sstd
   2316 
   2317 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (183,) (182,) 


Hard to tell without the data. Clearly, the message means that you (or scipy.stats.zscore) are trying to combine in a single operation an array of 182 values with an array of 183 values. Message may seem strange, with this "could not broadcast together" instead of "not the same shape". But that is because with numpy array, you don't necessarily need to have the same shape to combine 2 operands: along some axis, you could also have different sizes, as long as one of them is 1. In which case it is "broadcasted" (so, np.array([1])+np.array([4,5,6]_isnp.array([5,6,7]): [1]` is broadcasted)

But that being said, zscore(array) should return an array of the same shape as input. So, in that (very classical for a zscore) internal line of code of zscore, for some reason, either a is size 183 and mns size 182 ; or a and mns are both size 183 (or 1 for one of them) but then sstd is size 182.

What is the shape of daily_fraud.values? And its dtype ?

thanks for your help @chrslg for the shape I got "(183,)" . I must be doing something wrong, for dtype I put import pandas as pd daily_fraud.values.dtype and I got "dtype('O')"

Well, that is probably related. Not very clear why. But this means that your data are not numerical data (or at least are not stored as such). Hard to tell more without the data. What daily_fraud.head() is?

that was unexpected :
Date
2017-12-01    112
2017-12-02    123
2017-12-03     92
2017-12-04    115
2017-12-05    127
dtype: object
